# Is this the correct database structure for a sports team based database featuring countries and divisions?

Tags: mysql, database

I am looking to build a sports database where the user selects a country from a list 15 different countries, that then presents different divisions within that country.  The user then selects a division and is presented with a list of teams within that division to select.

One approach I had been advised to take is to have separate tables for Countries and Teams.

Table - Countries

Country | Teams (int array)

Table - Teams

ID (int) | Team Name | Division

The 'Teams (int array) would match with the ID of the team name in Teams Table.

I'm not 100% sure this is the correct approach.

What other solutions would be advisable?

Comment: Storing an array in one column is a bad advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create three tables. Something like

```
create table countries(
    id int unsigned auto_increment primary key,
    name varachar(100) not null,
    unique key (name)
);

create table divisions(
    id int unsigned auto_increment primary key,
    country_id int unsigned not null,
    name varchar(100) not null,
    unique key uk_name (name),
    foreign key fk_countries (country_id)
        references countries(id)
        on update restrict
        on delete cascade
);

create table teams(
    id int unsigned auto_increment primary key,
    division_id int unsigned not null,
    name varchar(100) not null,
    unique key uk_name (name),
    foreign key fk_divisions (division_id)
        references divisions(id)
        on update restrict
        on delete cascade
);
```

Your queries would be..

Show all countries:

```
select id, name from countries;
```

After the user selects a country you know the ID of that country and you can show all divisions from that country:

```
select id, name from divisions where county_id = ?;
```

Now the user selects a division and you get its ID - so you can show all teams from that division:

```
select id, name from teams where division_id = ?;
```

Comment: @Drew It was meant to be a pseudo code. But it accidentally became a valid SQL code ;-). First i didn't even want to define the data types, because all columns are self-explanatory. I mean it's clear that `county_id` is a FK to `countries` - isn't it? Now with all the details, the answer looks complex.

Comment: yeah I know. But you just saved a few jillion hours of debugging (perhaps) for some people that follower. Ok a stretch, but maybe.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to store the teams in the country table. Just have a countries table with the names of the countries. In the teams table, have an column for the country which uses the index of the country table. Now you can search for all teams in a given country. For example;

```
  select teamName, otherTeamData from teamTable where countryIndex = selectedCountryIndex and divisionIndex = selectedDivisionIndex;
```

You also need a divisions table which will likely have a countryIndex as well. Then you present a list of divisions specific to any country.